# Redirect to a URL on image click for changing after 5 sec

Tags: android, arraylist

I am trying to redirect to a particular URL when I am clicking on a image taken from drawable folder. I have taken an integer array to store all the images.

```
 final int[] imageArray = { R.drawable.advert1, R.drawable.arrow_blue_r,R.drawable.background4 };
```

I have used the following example to change the images after some interval on a image view with id advt_image

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    int i = 0;

    public void run() {
        advtImage.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
        Log.i("AdvtImage::::",""+advtImage);
        i++;
        if (i > imageArray.length - 1) {
            i = 0;
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000); // for interval...
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000); // for initial delay..
```

I couldnot figure out how can I use the Following intent every time a image chamges and user click on a particular image.

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
     Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
```

AnyHelp is highly appreciated on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep an array of URIs to use, using the index for your array of images to call the correct URI.

Sample code:

```
final int[] imageArray = { R.drawable.advert1, R.drawable.arrow_blue_r,R.drawable.background4 };
final String[] URLArray = {"http://www.stackoverflow.com","http://www.google.com","http://d.android.com"};

int position = 0;


final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        advtImage.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);
        Log.i("AdvtImage::::",""+advtImage);
        position++;
        if (position > imageArray.length - 1) {
            position = 0;
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000); // for interval...
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000); // for initial delay..
```

and then in your click, you can do

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
     Uri.parse(URLArray[position]);
```

Comment: How can I redirect to different URL every time one click on different image. I am trying to implement onCLickListener on advtImage and passing the intent but every time it is redirecting to same URL.

Comment: I'll update my answer with the quick code for it that you'll have to tailor to fit your code.